# Using Two-Way Binding with Custom Directive and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope

Starting this off by saying that I know a [common answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489298/angularjs-isolated-scope-two-way-binding-ng-repeat-not-working) for this is to put the `ng-repeat` inside the content of the directive, but in this case I can't figure out how that will work for this.

## Basic Problem

[image: General visual of problem showing letters in a box with the third letter highlighted.]

As the charCounter increases throughout the letter spans, I need to access the `offsetTop` value of each span in the `ng-repeat` in order to do some things, (When the `charCoutner` gets to a new line (has offsetTop > 0), adjust the `begin` variable that is in the `limitTo` in the ng-repeat).

### Struggling Point

I am not able to update a variable in the custom directive and make it accessible to the `ng-repeat`.

If I have the custom directive outside of the `ng-repeat` I have no access to the `offsetTop` of each span (but the `begin` variable updates).

`<p><span shell counter="charCounter" begin="begin"><span ng-repeat="letter in data | limitTo: limit : begin track by $index"><span>{{letter}}</span></span></span></p>`

**What I'm thinking that needs to happen is this**, but how do I get the `begin` variable to be updated?

`<p><span positioner counter="charCounter" begin="begin" ng-repeat="letter in data | limitTo: limit : begin track by $index"><span>{{letter}}</span></span></p>`

## Code Pen Sample

I've been playing around with this on Code Pen, You can see this problem in [code pen here:](http://codepen.io/theaemarie/pen/NNzjwo)

**UPDATE**

I've taken the example one step further and also integrated r0m4n's feedback about upping the `priority` of this and @Amy Blankenship's about further clarifying what I am trying to do. [Here is the updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/theaemarie/pen/PNaBdo). While this *technically* works, I'm not thinking I'd even need to do a custom directive now, since I'm accessing the element manually rather than using the `element` from the directive. I still have a delicate understanding of all this.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Even after looking at your code, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. I didn't see anywhere that you were even referencing offsetTop.

Comment: Oh, yeah, `offsetTop` is really stage 2 of my problem, and the end reasoning behind why I'm approaching the directive this way. Right now I'm just trying to get the variable `begin` to be shared with the custom directive and with `ng-repeat`.
I can put more of my code in another pen if it will help though, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope binding is having some priority issues. Take a look at using the priority property. Per the docs:

"When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied"

So you could do something like this:

```
myApp.directive('positioner', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1001,
    scope: {
      letter: '=',
      begin: '=',
      counter: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.begin += 5;
        console.info('begin', $scope.begin);
      }, 1000);

    }
  };
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: you mean using `priority` ?

Comment: Interesting. I'll play around with this now.